# What value after PDO PARAM STR mean?

Tags: php, pdo

I just what to know what number `12` means in this exemple:

```
$req->bindParam('titre', $titre, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
```

I don't really understand it.

Comment: You can read about bindParam in the manual [PDOStatement::bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indicates the length of the data type, in this case the length of the string parameter.

Comment: A note for the downvoter: if you think this post is not useful, you can vote to close it.